# Bash script: Cycle script until ffmpeg command restarts successfully

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have a IP Camera and the recordings are saved with ffmpeg RTSP into a raspberry pi.

Sometimes, when the electricity shuts off and comes back on, the raspberry boots faster than the IP Camera and the ffmpeg command (saved on a crontab to run every reboot) fails to execute because it can't reach the IP Camera (that is still turning on).

I tried to put a sleep command before the command but that doesn't work either.

It also happened that when the IP Camera reboots, the raspberry closes the command, but when the camera comes back online, I have to manually lauch the command.

Is there a way to make a script that waits to run the ffmpeg command until the camera is fully online (I assume with the $? variable for command exit status), and to wait to restart the ffmpeg command when the camera reboots?

The setup I have now is a crontab:
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot sleep 120s; sudo ffmpeg ...

Comment: Usually, ffmpeg doesn't self-background at all so I don't know why you'd need to do any of this. `while true; ffmpeg ...` should suffice. Use a systemd service (with appropriate tuning) if you want something to come up at boot and automatically restart whenever it fails. That also helps insofar as you can tell systemd to start a service only after other prerequisites are met (f/e, only after network configuration is complete), and you can have an `ExecStartPre` that waits until the camera in particular is on the network.

Comment: The Bash built-in command you are looking for is `until`. But first of all, it’s good to take a step back and stop using `crontab` altogether, `cron` is not just outdated, but outright broken and none of the ~5 different `cron` variants has ever worked too well. To keep a program alive, restart it as needed, make it uptime-aware and timing-aware, manage its dependencies on other system components, manage its logs, sandbox it and much more, `systemd` is the way to go. That also avoids awkward solutions based on a Bash loop with `until`.

Comment: Hello all, I tried using systemd with the After and Wants variables with the network.service service and enabling the custom service, but at restart the service always started and failed, even with After and/or Wants as options. The service would always start before network and obviously it didn't work because ffmpeg couldn't find the IP Camera.

Comment: Then how about `Restart=always` and `RestartSec=5` or some such? Also, `network.service` has nothing to do with the network being actually up. Everything runs in parallel with `systemd`, so `Wants` and `After` `network.service` merely means that _after_ `network.service` is **started** (not necessarily ready, _up_, or in any other well-defined state), something else will start. Maybe you are looking for `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` or `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` (or an equivalent unit for whatever network manager you are using).